# iPhone 6 orientation transform issue - UIWindow object

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, orientation, ios8

I found the issue while trying to update our project to adapt the change in iOS8 and iPhone6. After a series of testing and debugging, I do not know the reason that causes this issue. Only clue I found is that when creating `UIWindow` object in iPhone6, landscape, the UIWindow object has different angle (orientation) than the main screen (status bar angle). And after trying to transform the `UIWindow` object, it actually goes to a weird size. I do not know why and how this is happening. Your help is highly appreciated!!

[Environment]
Xcode 6.0.1
build 6A317
simulator: iPhone 6, iPhone 6+

[Issue]
There’s weird behavior occurred when trying to resize the UIWindow object to full screen (frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds )

[Normal Behavior] (OK)
1. Create UIWindow object in portrait orientation
2. Turn the device to landscape
3. UIWindow object will be resized to full screen
4. Resize OK

[Abnormal behavior] (FAIL) 
1. Create UIWindow object in landscape orientation
2. UIWindow object size correct, but orientation is wrong
3. After trying to transform to correct angle(orientation), the frame origin/size is messed up

[Test Result]
Testing simulator: iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+ 
Environment: Xcode 6.0.1, build 6A317, iOS8 simulator

[Screenshots link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pd87j330lwo3ug7/AADYzByzn9wSAbO9m9Cvq-tZa?dl=0)

Comment: saw this too.  like you, I only see this behavior on the iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Answer (score 5):

I have exactly the same issue after I upgrade my project to the new SDK and new device.

Just by adding an empty storyborad as launch screen in the project setting fixed this issue for me:
[image]

Comment: OHH!! Thank you for the enlightenment!! I will try it for my project!!

Comment: thanks for this.  it seems like any .xib will also work

Comment: You are my hero for all time.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Turns out I was calling initWithFrame on UIWindow with CGRect in pixels instead of points.